# ¿Como valido un string a true?

Tags: javascript

Consigna: "Solo podrán ingresar al sitio web personas de sexo femenino o con edad mayor a 21 años. Pero a su vez el administrador del sitio, puede ingresar también sin importar su edad"

Necesito ayuda para resolver este ejercicio y aun no entiendo, por que el string no valida para poder acceder a travez del else if

De otra manera. ¿Como se podria hacer? Ya que no domino muy bien el ciclo do while y se que es otra manera de hacerlo.

```js
var sexo = prompt("Indicar con F/M segun tu genero.");
var edad = prompt("¿Que edad tienes?");
var admin = "soy pedro";
var femenino = f;

if ((sexo = f) || (edad >=21)) {

  alert("Eres bienvenida.")
}

else if (sexo = String(admin) || (edad = String(admin))) {
  alert("Bienvenido administrador")
}

else {
  alert("No cumples con los requisitos. Lo sentimos.");
}
```

Comment: Dos errores: primero _f_ no esta declarado (si te refieres a femenino), segunda el signo `=` dentro de los if significar asignar, algo diferente a  `==` que es comparar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript es un lenguaje muy versátil, por lo que es VITAL que entiendas desde un inicio que las comparaciones se realizan mediante dos o tres signos igual (== ===).

Revisa el siguiente sitio web para que entiendas los detalles:
https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Por otro lado, el problema en tu código estaba en usar 1 solo signo de igualdad, además para hacer comparaciones de cadenas ("String"), se realiza diferente.

Si estás en un instituto o universidad, revisa la bibliografía que te han asignado; al margen de ello, siempre es bueno revisar la documentación:

Mozilla Development Network (MDN) tiene excelente información sobre javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript

```js
var sexo = prompt("Indicar con F/M segun tu genero.");
var edad = prompt("¿Que edad tienes?");
var admin = "soy pedro";
var femenino = "F";

if ((sexo === "F") || (edad >= 21)) {
  alert("Eres bienvenida.")
}else if (sexo === admin) {
  alert("Bienvenido administrador")
}else {
  alert("No cumples con los requisitos. Lo sentimos.");
}
```